# Do I need grub?

Tags: mac, grub, bootloader, arch-linux, refit

I installed Arch Linux on my iMac in its own partition. I'm using rEFIt to choose from Snow Leopard, Windows 7 and now Arch as well. I already install grub on Arch's partition when I installed Arch, but do I really need it? First I have to pick Arch from the rEFIt menu, then pick it again in the grub menu (and there are two items in it: Arch and Arch Fallback). So do I really need it? And if not how can I get rid of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against removing it. You definitely need something to boot the kernel, but I don't know if rEFIt can do it. Also if you screw up settings on Arch, you'd definately want to have fallback.

The easiest way to solve this would be to edit the timeout in grub.conf file. Just set it to 1 or 2 seconds so you can stop it if you need to actually do something in grub menu. I don't know where the grub.conf is in Arch, but check under /boot. There is a high probability that it would be there.

EDIT: My mistake. The file you need to edit is /boot/grub/menu.lst

Here's a link related to this question on Arch wiki: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave the timeout at 5 seconds and add `hiddenmenu`.